# Improve nested query in entity framework

Tags: c#, mysql, linq, entity-framework, subquery

I'm trying to write the linq to entity query as below:

```
var lst = (from rw in ctx.Reviews
           where rw.RefId == 10
              && rw.UpdatedTime == (from inner in ctx.CompareReviews
                                    where inner.RefId == 10
                                       && inner.ReviewNumber == rw.ReviewNumber
                                    select inner.UpdatedTime).Max()
           select rw).ToList();
```

I expect that it will generate to following query:

```
select *
from review rw
where rw.ref_id = 10
  and rw.updated_time = (select max(irw.updated_time)
                         from review irw
                         where irw.ref_id = 10
                           and irw.review_number = rw.review_number)
```

But it does not, it generates a query look like:

```
select rw.id,
       /* .. other fields */
       (
        select max(irw.updated_time)
        from review irw
        where irw.ref_id = 10
          and irw.review_number = rw.review_number
       ) as updated_time
from review rw
where rw.ref_id = 10
```

How can I make entity framework generate the first query.

Comment: is the result wrong or just the query is not in the form you expected? Entity Framework is sometimes optimizing the generated sql, and unless the resulting data is wrong, you shouldn't bother about that.

Comment: No, the result is true. But it takes about 10s to execute. My query (the first one) is about 0.3s

Comment: @TuTran, There is other ways to get better performance if you want to get latest row (single) based on updated_time field for ref_id=10. Please confirm if this is your requirement, so that I can share the query with you.

Comment: @ZafarMalik: Yes, that my requirement. I can speed up the query by spitting it into 2 steps. If you have a better way, please let me know

Answer (score 0):

Please try below query:

```
SELECT id, <other_columns> 
            FROM review
                        WHERE ref_id = 10
                        ORDER BY updated_time DESC limit1;
```

Note: ref_id and updated_time fields should be indexed.

---

As per your updated requirement:

```
SELECT review_number,id, <other_columns>
                         FROM 
                         (SELECT id,ref_id,<other_columns> FROM review
                         WHERE ref_id = 10
                         ORDER BY updated_time DESC) a
                         GROUP BY review_number;
```

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. I forgot to tell you that my table has `review_number` field (see my OP). Each `review_number` has many records, which I want to get the latest record based on latest `updated_time`

Comment: Thanks for you help, but your query does not work. In addition, seems you misunderstood what I'm asking. I try to use entity framework and the first query which I post work well, just generated query is slow.